# Batch file checks if program is responding

Tags: batch-file

I was wondering if there was a way to check if a program was responding or not (the way it appears in taskmgr.exe)  Basically I am making my own killer for a GTA game.  How I want it to work is the batch file checks every so often if the program is responding correctly or not.  If the program doesn't respond for around ten seconds, the task is killed.
I have no idea how to check if the program is responding or not with a batch file.  If anyone has anything to help out, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: It figures when I _want_ a program to stop responding, it won't.  Does the name show up as _x (not responding)_ when you perform the `tasklist` command?

Comment: @Gary When I sent a proram not responding (I had to crash my C# application), It didn't come up with anything like that, so no that wont work.

Comment: The only way I can imagine doing this in batch script is to make it sense if a window pops up (the form which informs you the program is not reponding and gives you the option to close it [but does not always work]), and then see what was the last process to be started before that. If you only want to build this for GTA, you could specify so but then if any application goes not responding, GTA will be closed. If you don't mind that, tell me and I'll make the code.

Comment: @Monacraft I never thought about using that popup window...  My computer isn't that great, so before I play san andreas, I have to free up as much cpu as possible, even shutting down WMI, so I shouldn't have to worrry about another program not responding.  I am pretty sure I know how to code it, but I would like to see how an expert would do it, so if you wouldn't mind...

Comment: EDIT to my last comment^  Wouldn't that be pointless, killing the program WHEN you get the pop up?  It would only need to be done when the popup isn't there.

Comment: How about `tasklist -fi "STATUS eq not responding"`?  This same filter can be applied to `taskkill` instead (be sure to specify image name).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Gary's piece of code:

```
start "C:\... [path to gta.exe (inclusive)]"
:loop
taskkill /im "[GTA image name]" /fi "STATUS eq NOT RESPONDING"
goto loop
```

That should work. Just save it and run it every time you want to play GTA, it will start it GTA.

Mona