# Batch file to kill and restart not responding program

Tags: file, batch-file, kill

I am running a program (Win7) which sometimes gets stuck and not responding.

Just wanted your help to write batch process that can check the program status and if it's Not responding then close and open it again

Comment: check it if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18070478/batch-file-checks-if-program-is-responding

Comment: Thank - But i'm not sure how to write the code right
`@echo off
taskkill /im "Be2Beat.exe" /fi "STATUS eq NOT RESPONDING"

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Be2Beat\Be2Beat Multimedia Platform\Be2Beat.exe"

exit
) || (
exit
)`

Comment: I want the batch to check if program not responding to close it and launch again and if its working good just exit without running it again. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Test this: it should only relaunch be2beat when the task is not responding, and has been killed forcefully.

```
@echo off 
taskkill /im "Be2Beat.exe" /fi "STATUS eq NOT RESPONDING" /f >nul && start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Be2Beat\Be2Beat Multimedia Platform\Be2Beat.exe"
```

Comment: Thanks!!! - One last question - How can i make it close the Cmd window after batch file execute?

Comment: Try it using the start command as I've shown above.  The cmd prompt window should close by itself.

Comment: Thank you. The only thing is that the window closes if it actually opens the program `start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Be2Beat\Be2Beat Multimedia Platform\Be2Beat.exe"` but if the program already running the windows doesn't close. Sorry about me driving you crazy :) appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: Do you click on the batch file?  It should close by itself, but try putting an `exit` command as the last line.  If you called the batch file `taskkill` then call it something else.

Comment: Thanks! One more thing... How can i add this action `C:\Check\Curl` if only if program not responding and the app killed it and opened it again? I will just send me email regarding this action. Thanks a lot - appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

This will run it on a continuous loop to monitor.

Create file 2.bat

```
@echo off
:loop
taskkill /im "Be2Beat.exe" /fi "STATUS eq NOT RESPONDING" /f >nul && start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Be2Beat\Be2Beat Multimedia Platform\Be2Beat.exe"
goto loop
```